# SQL TOP 1 issue when no record is found

Tags: sql

Hope you can help me with this SQL issue I am unable to solve:

I have a price list file with multiple entries per item number like this:

- ItemNo
- ValidFrom
- ValidTo
- Price

Now when I try to generate a list with prices valid today, I use the statement below to get a decent report. I only have a problem when no valid price was found, i.e. for TODAY there is no record. In this case the first TOP 1 subquery still returns a (random?) value and destroys my report.

I assume that TOP 1 will always return one value by definition, or is there a trick which can prevent this?

Really appreciate your help! (and please excuse the german terms in the query...)

```
SELECT 
   MITBAL.MBITNO as 'Artikel', MITMAS.MMITDS as 'Bezeichnung', 
   MITBAL.MBBUYE as 'Disponent', MITMAS.MMNEWE as 'Gewicht', 
   MITBAL.MBSUNO as 'Lieferant', MMITTY as 'Typ', 
   m9ucos as 'Std.-Kosten', idsunm as 'Lieferantenname', 
   iicucd as 'WSL', MBEOQT as 'EOQ',

   (select count(*) 
    from RCE12_Staging.dbo.mpagrl 
    left outer join RCE12_Staging.dbo.mpagrh on aicono = ahcono 
                                             and aiagnb = ahagnb and aisuno = ahsuno 
    where aicono = 2 
    and aiobv1 = mbitno and aisagl = 20 
    and aisuno between '400000' and '599999' and aigrpi = 40 
    and aiuvdt >= CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112) and ahpast = '40') as 'Anz.Lief',

   (select TOP 1 ajpupr 
    from RCE12_Staging.dbo.mpagrp
    left outer join RCE12_Staging.dbo.mpagrh on ajcono = ahcono 
                           and ajagnb = ahagnb and ajsuno = ahsuno 
    left outer join RCE12_Staging.dbo.mpagrl on ajcono = aicono 
                           and ajagnb = aiagnb and ajsuno = aisuno 
    where ajcono = 2 
    and ajobv1 = mbitno and ajsuno = mbsuno 
    and ajmapr = 1 and ajgrpi = 40 
    and ajfvdt < CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112) and ahpast = '40' 
    and ahfvdt < CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112) 
    and ahuvdt >= CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112) 
    and aisagl = 20 and aigrpi = 40 
    and aifvdt < CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112) 
    and aiuvdt >= CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112) 
    order by ajfvdt desc) as 'EK-Preis',

   (select TOP 1 ajfrqt 
    from RCE12_Staging.dbo.mpagrp
    left outer join RCE12_Staging.dbo.mpagrh on ajcono = ahcono 
                             and ajagnb = ahagnb and ajsuno = ahsuno 
    left outer join RCE12_Staging.dbo.mpagrl on ajcono = aicono 
                             and ajagnb = aiagnb and ajsuno = aisuno 
    where ajcono = 2 and ajobv1 = mbitno 
    and ajsuno = mbsuno and ajmapr = 1 and ajgrpi = 40 
    and ajfvdt < CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112) and ahpast = '40' 
    and ahfvdt < CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112) 
    and ahuvdt >= CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112) and aisagl = 20 
    and aigrpi = 40 
    and aifvdt < CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112) 
    and aiuvdt >= CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112) 
    order by ajfvdt desc) as 'EK-Menge'

FROM 
    RCE12_Staging.dbo.MITBAL MITBAL
left outer join 
    RCE12_Staging.dbo.MITFAC MITFAC ON mbcono = m9cono and mbitno = m9itno and m9faci = 'DFP'
left outer join 
    RCE12_Staging.dbo.MITMAS MITMAS ON mbcono = mmcono and mbitno = mmitno
left outer join 
    RCE12_Staging.dbo.CIDMAS CIDMAS ON mbcono = idcono and mbsuno = idsuno
left outer join 
     RCE12_Staging.dbo.CIDVEN CIDVEN ON mbcono = iicono and mbsuno = iisuno

WHERE 
    MITBAL.MBCONO = 2 
    AND MITBAL.MBWHLO = '200' AND MBSTAT = '20' AND MBPUIT = '2' 
    and MBITNO like '479200222%'

ORDER BY MBITNO
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: If you run the statement but delete the 'TOP 1' do you receive results?  If so the issue is with your query and not the 'TOP 1'.

Comment: Also: try to **reduce** your problem to the minimum query that shows the issue you're having. We don't need all those WHERE conditions and ten sample of a `SELECT TOP 1 ...` subquery - reduce it to **just show** the problem - don't dump such a huge, hard-to-read query on us......

Answer (score 0):

The 'top 1' will return the first row from the dataset if the dataset you have requested is empty then top 1 will return an empty dataset with no rows and no 'Random data'.

You should probably check the number of rows returned if you need the data for later in the query or initialise a variable and use that.

Comment: Thanks for the input, you pointed me in the right direction. Issue solved.